# Anuncio AdMob aparece apenas uma vez

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, admob, libgdx

Olá, alguém pode me ajudar com esse problema?
Quando rodo meu app no emulador, o anuncio aparece normalmente a todo momento, porem quando vou rodar no meu celular o anuncio apareceu apenas uma vez e não voltou a aparecer.
O que pode ser isso? Estou usando a biblioteca Gdx para o meu game

Class Android Launcher

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements AdHandler {

    private static final String TAG = "AndroidLauncher";
    private final int SHOW_ADS = 1;
    private final int HIDE_ADS = 0;
    protected AdView adView;

    Handler handler = new Handler(){

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what){
                case SHOW_ADS:
                    adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case HIDE_ADS:
                    adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        View gameView = initializeForView(new BolsoBird(this), config);
        layout.addView(gameView);

        adView = new AdView(this);

        adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                int visibility  = adView.getVisibility();
                adView.setVisibility(AdView.GONE);
                adView.setVisibility(visibility);
                Log.i(TAG,"Ad loaded...");
            }
        });
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId("xxxxxxx");

        AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );

        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

        layout.addView(adView, adParams);

        adView.loadAd(builder.build());
        setContentView(layout);
    }

    @Override
    public void showAds(boolean show) {
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(show ? SHOW_ADS : HIDE_ADS);
    }
}
```

Estou inicializando o anuncio no metodo create, do meu jogo..

```
public void create () {
         .....
         .....
        handler.showAds(toggle); //toggle é sempre true..

    }
```

Comment: Voltou a aparecer no meu celular por um tempo, mas não aparece mais, é algum tipo de "bloqueio" ? Testei no celular da minha mãe e do meu amigo, e o anuncio está aparecendo...

Comment: tenta por a chamada para o teu `showAds(...);` num metodo onResume